# For each loop in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, foreach, for-loop

How do I use for loop in vb.net something like

```
dim start as integer
Dim customers as New List(Of Customers)

Customers=dataAcess.GetCustomers()

For each start=500 in  Customers.count
  'Do something here'
Next
```

I want to process some data for each 500 customers.. Please help

Comment: Do you mean you want the loop to iterate on the List of Customers in chunks of 500?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "each 500 customers"?

Comment: don't create a "new" list of customers if you're just going to replace it on the next line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, don't create a `New` list of customers if you're just going to assign a different list to the variable on the next line.  That's kinda dumb. Do it like this:

```vb
Dim customers As List(Of Customer) = dataAccess.GetCustomers()
```

Then, for the loop you need a plain `For` loop rather than a `For Each`. Don't forget to stop *before* the count of items, since for .Net the first index is 0 instead of 1:

```vb
For i As Integer = 500 To Customers.Count -1 
    ' Do something with Customers(i) here
Next i
```

If you're using Visual Studio 2008 or later you could also write it like this:

```vb
For Each item As Customer in  Customers.Skip(500)
   ' Do something with "item" here
Next
```

Answer (score 12):

Try the following

```vb
For Each current In customers
    ' Do something here 
    Console.WriteLine(current.Name)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

'This will start at 500 and process to the end....

```
for start as integer = 500 to Customers.Count

'process customer....
customer = Customers(start)

Next
```

To iterate the entire list:

```
for each cust as Customer in Customers

Next
```

One note.... VB is case insensitive and your sample code seems to use lower case and upper case customers

Comment: When I try this for start as integer = 500 to Customer.Count
I am getting an error saying customer cannot be converted to int

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:-

```
Dim customers as New List(Of Customer)

Customers=dataAcess.GetCustomers()

For Each customer AS Customer in  Customers
   '' // do something with the customer object
Next
```

**Edit**

Sounds like you want to select 500 of N items or perhaps the next 500.  You could use the LINQ extension methods `.Take` and/or `.Skip` to achieve this.  Use ToList then to create your list.  E.g.:-

```
Dim customers as List(Of Customer)
customers = dataAccess.GetCustomers().Skip(500).Take(500).ToList()
```

If all you want to do enum through the customers then you could dispense with ToList().

Comment: I want to do it for each 500 customers.

Comment: Do you mean you want to do it for every 500th customer, perhaps? It is still unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can either try:

```
    For i As Integer = 500 To (customers.Count -1)
        ''do something
    Next
```

Or

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To (customers.Count - 1) step 500
        ''do something
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim start as Integer
Dim customers as New List(Of Customers)

Customers = dataAcess.GetCustomers()

For i as Integer = start to Customers.count Step 500
    Debug.Print Customers(i).someProperty
    Do something here
Next i
```

I think you need to use the Customer index and Step in 500s. This will only process customer(start), Customer(start+500), Customer(start+1000) etc, not all the customers. Is that what you intend?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but maybe you could try this:

```
Dim count As Integer = 0
Const MAX_CUSTOMERS As Integer = 500
Dim customers As List(Of Customers) = dataAcess.GetCustomers()

For Each c As Customer In customers
    'do stuff here'
    c.Name = "Billy"
    count+=1

    If count = MAX_CUSTOMERS Then Exit For
Next
```

It's not elegant by any means, but it makes sense and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, there is no shortage of variety.  I don't recognize your "DataAcess" object type, but if you can pull that table in as a Recordset (i.e. a SQL table) then try this. (Don't forget to return the recordset when your done)

```
Option Explicit

Dim Customers As Recordset
Set Customers=currentdb.openrecordset("???")

While Customers.EOF=False
   'do stuff here using the recordset object
   'i.e. Customers.Fields("Name")="Billy"
   Customers.MoveNext
Wend
```